# can we add extra items to gallery of libre office writer

Tags: libreoffice, drag-and-drop

is there any way that we can follow and add extra items into the gallery of libre office office writer. i am currently working on a big project and i want some extra images and icons.Doing so with the typical method of copy pasting makes the work lengthy that is the reason for asking this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Open ClipArt package from the Ubuntu Software Center.